# Filter Workbook Column based on data found in another Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I have two Workbooks and I’m trying to filter “Wbk2” Column A based on the data found in Column C of “Wbk1” There are a few hundred cells in “Wbk1”Column C that I’m trying to match up with “Wbk2” Column A  and filter based on that.

It works just fine when you set to a single cell. I’m trying to add the entire column as a filter and cannot seem to get it to filter based on that criteria.

```
sub filter()

Dim Wbk1 As Workbook
Dim Wbk2 As Worksheet
Dim Wksht As Worksheet
Dim Filter As Range


Set Wbk1 = Workbooks(“DataToUseForFiltering.xlsm”)
Set Wksht = Wbk1.Worksheets(“Sheet1”)
Set Wbk2 = ActiveSheet

With Wksht
 Set Filter = .Range(“C2”)
End With

With Wbk2
 With .Range("A1:Z1" & Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
 .AutoFilter
 .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criterial:=Filter
 End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest you use a `Isnumber(Match` function instead to compare the two. (Or powerquery)

Comment: Just nitpicking.... `Wbk2` is declared as a `Worksheet`, this is misleading.  Also,  'Cells(` references the `ActiveSheet` and should probably be preceded by a comma `.Cells(`

Comment: @Gitty thank you. I will research both

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious ... you are correct, I was going cross eyed and didn't even notice, thanks!

Comment: @futureisnow Oops, I meant "period" not "comma", a comma will generate an error.  I would like to help you solve your problem but I'm not sure exactly what it is it how your data is generated.  That said, I know `AutoFilter` can accept arrays but I'm not so sure about ranges. You're passing a range, what happens if you write the values of the range into a one dimensional array and use this array as`Criteria1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code builds on my earlier comments and has been tested.

```
Option Explicit

Sub NewFilter()

    Dim Wbk1 As Workbook
    Dim Wksht1 As Worksheet
    Dim Wksht2 As Worksheet
    Dim rngFilter As Range
    Dim aryFilter()
    Dim i As Long

    Set Wbk1 = Workbooks("DataToUseForFiltering.xlsm")
    Set Wksht1 = Wbk1.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Wksht2 = ActiveSheet

    With Wksht1
        Set rngFilter = .Range("C2:C" & .UsedRange.Rows.Count)
    End With

    ReDim aryFilter(1 To rngFilter.Cells.Count)

    For i = 1 To rngFilter.Cells.Count
        aryFilter(i) = rngFilter.Cells(i).Value
    Next i

    Wksht2.Rows(1).AutoFilter _
        Field:=1, _
        Criteria1:=aryFilter, _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the help I really appreciate it. I tested your code, the only thing it didn't like were the quotes from mobile (which is cool that you did). It appears to filter for the last cell with data from Column "C" only instead of all the cells from Column "C"

Comment: @futureisnow I've updated the answer with tested code

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help